# Invalid JSON Error at POST/PUT json with special characters using nodejs http.request()

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, couchdb

I'm using node.js http module to PUT a json data into CouchDB. This json contains a special character "ä" which causes CouchDB responding with "invalid_json" error. Once this special char is removed or replaced, the data is saved successfully. My node.js code:

```
var data = {
    "a": "Gerät"
};

var stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data);

var http = http || require("http");

var requestOptions = {
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "5984",
    "method": "PUT",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Content-Length": stringifiedData.length
    },
    "path": "/testdb/test"
};

var req = http.request(requestOptions, function (res) {
    res.setEncoding("utf8");
    res.on("data", function (chunk) {
      console.log("Response: " + chunk);
    });
});

console.log("stringifiedData: ", stringifiedData);

req.end(stringifiedData);
```

The interesting thing is, if I save this data into a json file and use curl command to PUT it into CouchDB, the data is saved without any problem.

```
curl -X PUT -d @test.json http://localhost:5984/testdb/test
```

Do I miss some encoding configurations at using nodejs http.request()? I tried with converting "Gerät" to 'utf8' encoding: `Buffer.from("Gerät", "latin1").toString("utf8);` but it didn't help.

The same issue exists with POSTing a json containing this special character to CouchDB `/_bulk_docs` API.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that you are including the string length for the `Content-Length`, but not the length in bytes -- special characters can have longer lengths.  Try changing the line to this:

```
var stringifiedData = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data));
```

This should allow the content length to be correct.

[Forum post discussing issue](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/lDrmZHM_IDM/ZwMbPbVJHjgJ)

Comment: Using encodeURIComponent() ends up saving `Ger%C3%A4t` instead of `Gerät` into CouchDB.

Comment: In that case the server side likely needs to decode it (many do this automatically), most server side languages have something similar to javascript's [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Will. That node.js script is already sitting on the server side and the PUT request is directly sent to the CouchDB url API. There's no further handling beyond this point.

Comment: Ok I think I found a solution, I'll update my answer shortly

Comment: Thanks so much, Will. The solution of calculating the correct content length works perfectly!